# Node.js pattern for root_url in production or development

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

Relatively new to web development, and I don't know of a pattern to solve the following problem. In my Node.js app, I might use the request library to make a HTTP request to a resource on a server, and on the server I can check whether I am in development or production like so:

```
if('production' == process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

but on the front-end, using Backbone for instance,

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/api/players' //hardcoded for development only
});
```

How can I avoid hardcoding "localhost" into my front-end, by checking whether it is a development or production server?

What is the best pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: one solution I have discovered is to simply use relative paths so instead of 'http://localhost:3000/api/players' simply make it '/api/players'

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach your environmental properties to your window (or more preferably you application namespace).

```
//Attach and object to the window
window.ENV = {};
//Add an environmental variable (that can be written by the server)
window.ENV.app_env = 'development';

//Keep all dev/test/prod urls in an object...
var server_urls = {
    development: 'localhost:8080',
    test: '192.168.0.2:3030',
    production: 'mysite.co.uk',
}
//...

//Then build the url when you need it.
var server_url = server_urls[window.ENV.app_env];
```